# Auto mounting Win Server share drive with spaces in folder name

Tags: windows, file-sharing

I've just setup my Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspian OS version 10\Buster) with Jellyfin.
All my media (for Jellyfin) is on a Win 2016 Server (running AD\DNS\DHCP) in different folders.

I setup mapping to the Movies folder on the Win Server (which works - and ive got Jellyfin to index the content) via modifying /etc/fstab with this line;
`//192.168.0.10/Movies /home/pi/Server/Movies cifs username=username,password=password 0 0`
& giving Jellyfin the movies folder location as /home/pi/Server/Movies.  Obviously the new folders were created in /hom/pi/... before hand.

But, my TV shows are in a folder on the Win Server with a space in the name - so its at `//192.168.0.10/TV Shows`
I tested being able to mount this just via a simple (with a single quotation mark surrounding the address):
`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=password '//192.168.0.10/TV Shows' Server/TV-Shows` which worked fine.

but it appears i can't use the single quotation marks in fstab as it wont map to it with:
`'//192.168.0.10/TV Shows' /home/pi/Server/TV-Shows cifs username=username,password=password 0 0`

Any suggestions?
Or am i missing something else?

Edit note - if i run `sudo mount -av` i get a parse error on the line for TV Shows folder whether i use: `'//192.168.0.10/TV Shows' /home/pi/Server/TV-Shows cifs username=username,password=password 0 0` or if i use `//192.168.0.10/TV Shows /home/pi/Server/TV-Shows cifs username=username,password=password 0 0`
I also tried to use an escape with this:
`//192.168.0.10/TV\ Shows /home/pi/Server/TV-Shows cifs username=username,password=password 0 0` but still got the parse error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer after more googling around debian...
fstab has it's own syntax - you have to specify its code-point as a zero padded 3-digit octal number preceded by a backslash.
thanks to this post:
https://superuser.com/questions/527495/how-to-mount-partition-with-spaces-in-path

so where i was trying to do: `//192.168.0.10/TV Shows /home/pi/Server/TV-Shows cifs username=username,password=password 0 0`, well it needs to be expressed as:
`//192.168.0.10/TV\040Shows /home/pi/Server/TV-Shows cifs username=username,password=password 0 0`.

Thus `\040` defines a space.